# How to blink leds with for cycle on .C with Texas MSP430

Tags: c, msp430

I'm new in the C language and im trying to make a luck fortune with leds, it will "spin" blinking the 8 leds in order and then blink only the winner one but i dont know if i can do it in C without making a case switch for every P2OUT of the microcontroller (the interrupt is because it will interact with a bluetooth module across with a cellphone application )

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // libreria para el uso de rand()
#include<time.h>
int x;
int a;
int numero;
volatile int Counter=0;
/**
 * main.c
 */


#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A (void){
    Counter--;     //Disminuir el Contador en 1
    LPM3_EXIT;      //Salir del modo de bajo poder 3
}

   void wait(int seconds){
       Counter= seconds*2;
       while(Counter){
           LPM3;
       }
   }


void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    BCSCTL1= CALBC1_1MHZ;
    DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;

    P1SEL=0x06;
    P1SEL2=0x06;


    P2SEL=0x0;
    P2SEL2=0x0;
    P2DIR=0xFF;
    P2OUT=0x00;

    UCA0CTL1=0x81;//Enabled USCI logic held in reset state
    UCA0CTL0=0x0;//UART Mode, Odd Parity, 8bit Data, 1 bit de parada, asynchronous
    UCA0BR0=0x68;//Baud rate 9600
    UCA0BR1=0x0;//Baud rate (UCA0BR0+UCA0BR1x256=9600)
    UCA0MCTL=0x2;
    UCA0STAT=0x0;
    UCA0CTL1 =0x80;//Disabled USCI logic held in reset state
    IE2=1;

   __enable_interrupt();



    for (;;){
        
        
        if (a==49){  // 1 recieved from bluetooth "49" in code ASCII

               srand (time(NULL));  //seed  of random number based on the time
               numero = rand(1,9);    //generated random number between 1 and 9
               for(int i=0,i<9,i++){
                   P2OUT=BIT(i);  //HELP HERE BLINKING THE LEDS WITH CYCLE FOR 
                   wait(5) //function of delay
               }
               P2OUT=;

           }
}

        }

 }

#pragma vector=USCIAB0RX_VECTOR  //interruption for bluetooth module HC-05
__interrupt void uartbt(void)
      {
    a=UCA0RXBUF;//INTERRUPCION DONDE SE ALMACENA EL VALOR CUANDO HAY COMUNICACION EN EL BLUETOOTH
    IFG2=0;//Limpiamos bandera de interrupción para salir
   }
```

Comment: This should answer your question: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Comment: Oh yes it gives me a clue and it remembered me the classes i had of what the "<<" does, thank you